# Determining the initial positions of Engima's rotors

Tags: brute-force-attack, known-plaintext-attack, enigma

We want to perform a known plaintext attack on the enigma M3, the goal is to reach the initial settings of the 3 rotors. I tried to bruteforce those values since I know the plaintext, ciphertext, positions of the rotors and the reflector setting, but I couldn't find the initial position of the 3 rotors.
Is there any method/calculation to perform in order to make my life easier? the challenge is the following:
$aaaaa: yugzy$ with the parameters:

- Position of the rotors: **I, III, II**
- Reflector setting: **UKW-B**
- Ring setting: **A,A,A**

I tried to use visualizers such as: https://www.101computing.net/enigma-machine-emulator/ but still, I wasn't successful to find the result.

Comment: Because there is none. If "a"  maps to "y", it cannot map to "u", "g" and "z" at the same time. It would be useful to learn how an Enigma works before trying to break one. If you were to say there are steckered pairs, it is a whole new ball game. Another tip: think indicator-ring offset. Indicator shown in a window and ring setting are interdependent variables as far as the orientation of the wiring core concerned.